# How can I lock tables for read only without a session in MariaDB 10.4.21?

Tags: mysql, automation, ansible, mariadb

I am trying to automate the backup process of MariaDB with Ansible for replication purposes. During the process, I have to lock tables in MariaDB to prevent an update in order to preserve the right position in binary log file which I am going to store in a variable after the backup. After registering the position variable, I will unlock the tables.

I did the process manually by hand at first and no other sessions were able to execute non-read queries. However, when I execute the query from ansible command module
-> `mysql -u root -p -e "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;"`, the query gets executed but I still can update the database. I believe this is because I don't hold any sessions during the process.

So, is there any way I can lock all the tables without holding a session?

Comment: You can't as any locks are held for the duration of a transactions or an active connection.

Comment: Is it doable by changing the configuration file ? Tried "read_only = 1" but it didn't work.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to reinvent the wheel? There are plenty mysql backup tools out there!

Comment: I definitely have no reason actually, just realized that the mariabackup also stores the binlog info. Thank you.